# Minimal polynomial of sum of cube roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, minimal-polynomials

I think the title fully describes this problem.

I need to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}$. I have tried doing what I'd normally do for sums of square roots but nothing works. WolframAlpha cannot give the answer for general $a$ and $b$. Is someone on this site able to provide the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ (or more generally, $a, b \in K$ and we are looking for a minimal polynomial over $K$).

Put $x := \sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b}$. Then

$$x^3 = a + b + 3\sqrt[3]{a} \sqrt[3]{b} ( \sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b} ) = a + b + 3 \sqrt[3]{a} \sqrt[3]{b} \cdot x,$$

so

$$(x^3-a-b)^3 = 27ab \cdot x^3$$

which simplifies to

$$x^9 - 3(a+b) \cdot x^6 + (3(a+b)^2 - 27ab) \cdot x^3 - (a+b)^3 = 0.$$

So we have found a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ (or $K$) which has a zero at $\sqrt[3]{a} + \sqrt[3]{b}$. If $a$ and $b$ are "sufficiently independent", this will be the minimal polynomial of that number. But it may happen that it is not, for example $\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{16}$ simplifies to $3 \sqrt[3]{2}$ and so its minimal polynomial is of degree $3$.

In the case $K = \mathbb{Q}$ with a little more work I believe it is possible to give an explicit condition for $a, b$ equivalent to the fact that the above polynomial is minimal, but I'm not sure if you're interested.

Comment: This is fine (+1). I just wanted to give $\root3\of2+\root3\of4$ as a different kind of sume of cube roots with a cubic minimal polynomial.

Comment: This is very good. I got the same result by a method that is much more elaborate and much less instructive.